# Why is flow unable to determine more precisely the type in this example of a functional Either?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have some code that plays around with some functional javascript concepts such as Eithers, as presented by Brian Lonsdorf in [this series](https://egghead.io/courses/professor-frisby-introduces-composable-functional-javascript).

I've been trying to type an Either expression. Here's my attempt:

```
type RightApi<X> = {
  map: <C: *>(f: X => C) => RightApi<C>,
  fold: <C: *>(f: Function, g: X => C) => C
};

const Right = <X: *>(x: X): RightApi<X> => ({
  map: f => Right(f(x)),
  fold: (f, g) => g(x),
})

type LeftApi<X> = {
  map: (f: Function) => LeftApi<X>,
  fold: <C: *>(f: X => C, g: Function) => C,
};

const Left = <X: *>(x: X): LeftApi<X> => ({
  map: f => Left(x),
  fold: (f, g) => f(x),
});

const fromMayBeNullOrUndefined = <X: *>(x: X) =>
  ((x === null || x === undefined) ? Left(x) : Right(x));

const test = fromMayBeNullOrUndefined(3).fold(x => null, x => x);
// null | number
```

[link](https://flow.org/try/#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)

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite get me as far as I'd like. On the last line, I try to test the typing. Logically, it seems clear to me that `test` will be a `number`. Because the value provided to `fromMayBeNullOrUndefined` is `3`, i.e. not null or undefined, so when `fold` is called, the right-hand function should be called.

Have I made a mistake here? Or is it not possible for flow to infer the result more precisely?

Comment: Does Flow actually try to perform dynamic analysis in a case like that?

Comment: Good question. It was my understanding that it does. That a syntax like this `<X: *>(x: X) => x` would be sensitive to the arguments with which a function is called. But looking at this [simple example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzCjjjAF4wAeADQC5kA+ACgA97qBKchsFgblRghwoZhwEwAQwDK+AE4BLbAHNyREkwDkAI0lzNHAVjyFJAOQCuAW20BTOWuJwmAZkNA), I think what it is doing rather is considering all the possibilities given the arguments provided.

Answer (score 1):

Your mentioned problem can be solved by defining different type signatures for the `fromMaybeOrUndefined` function like so:

```
declare function fromMayBeNullOrUndefined(x: null | void): LeftApi<null | void>;
declare function fromMayBeNullOrUndefined<X>(x: X): RightApi<X>;
function fromMayBeNullOrUndefined<X>(x: X) {
  if (x === null || x === undefined) {
    return Left(x);
  }
  return Right(x);
}
```

Now test properly typechecks:

```
const test: null = fromMayBeNullOrUndefined(null).fold(x => null, x => x);

const test: number = fromMayBeNullOrUndefined(3).fold(x => null, x => x);
```

**But** while this is a fun excersise it is completely missing the point of the `Either` type:

The point of `Either` is that `Left` and `Right` have the same API so that **at runtime** the underlying value (or often called data) can be *either* of them. Whether the value is `Left` or `Right` is transparent. This is important because you would use the `Either` type (or any kind of Monad really) when there is some kind of external influence that can have two results. For example you want to connect to a database - the connection can *either* be created or it fails. Or in your case the user of some API might provide *either* a number or a null value.

```
/* @flow */
type Either<L, R> = {
  map: <T>(f: R => T) => Either<L, T>,
  fold: <T>(f: L => T, g: R => T) => T
};

const Right = <R>(x: R): Either<any, R> => ({
  map: <T>(f: R => T): Either<any, T> => Right(f(x)),
  fold: <T>(f: any => T, g: R => T): T => g(x),
})

const Left = <L>(x: L): Either<L, any> => ({
  map: <T>(f: any => T): Either<any, T> => Left(x),
  fold: <T>(f: L => T, g: any => T): T => f(x),
});

const fromMayBeNullOrUndefined = <X>(x: X): Either<null | void, X> =>
  ((x === null || x === undefined) ? Left(x) : Right(x));

const test = fromMayBeNullOrUndefined(3).fold(x => null, x => x);
(test: null | number)
```

With `Either` you can continue coding in "the happy path" (on the right) until you want to fold back together the paths of execution. Example:

```
function getAccountBalance(name: string): string {
  const account: Either<Error, Account> = getAccountByCustomerName(name);

  return account
    .map(account => account.balance)
    .fold(
      () => "Seems like you don't have an account at our service",
      balance => `Your balance is ${balance}`,
    );
}
```

This example will get way more interesting when there are multiple operations happening as explained in the next video lecture.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it not possible for flow to infer the result more precisely?

Type inference stops at function boundaries. It would be too fragile if the body of one function could affect type-checking in another. The only time that the actual body of a function is considered is when type-checking that function against its own type.

So while, yes, you can peer inside `fromMayBeNullOrUndefined` and know that the result of `Left` or `Right` is dependent on whether `x` is `null`/`undefined` or not, it's not reasonable to expect Flow to do the same. It would also break the abstraction of a function if you had to look into the source code to find out how to make it type-check.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is one of two things that Flow can now provide.

1. `%checks` a.k.a. [Predicate Functions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions)
2. `$NonMaybeType<T>`, which is all the types supplied except `null` and `undefined`.

Also, `Function` types in Flow are [treated as "unsafe"](https://flow.org/en/docs/linting/rule-reference/#toc-unclear-type), so providing a more specific type definition will help.

In the cases of `map()` and `fold()`, you may want to look into [the `$Call<T>` type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call), which allows you to call a function on the type statically at *author* time.

Hope this helps.